# Powerview drop filter context on a column

Tags: excel, powerpivot, powerview

I'm currently working on a power view project where I need to display the numbers of the gross market and compare these to the numbers of a certain customer.

In this particular example, the market has sales in clothing, food, entertainment and electronics. However, in the dataset, the customer only has records for clothing and food (so they didn't sell in the other fields, this isn't missing data).

When I now make a pivot table in power pivot with this data (with the customer as a filter, but with DAX formulas to drop the filter to display the gross market sales) , I correctly get what I want. Quick example:

CLOTHING 11654$ 2541$
FOOD 325477$ 4356$
ENTERTAINMENT 22234$
ELECTRONICS 70124$

Now, when I try to do this exact thing in Powerview, the matrix (with again the customer as filter) doesn't show the numbers for entertainment and electronics, because the matrix is filtered.

Is there a way to drop a filter on rows or columns? I already tried 'show items with no data' but to no prevail.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try either of these and see if it works:

1. in the data model --> [Column]-->Advanced --> Summerize By --> Do Not Summerize
2. add gross market to view filter in power view.